# IDE complains Config files referenced in ConfigSource attributes do not comply with DotNetConfig.xsd

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, xsd, app-config, configuration-files

I find configsource references in the .config-files to be very helpful. However, since these referenced config-files only contain fragments of the entire app.config hierarchy, the IDE complains.

In the app.config file:

```
  <configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="customProfiles" type="SomeConfigClass, SomeAssembly"/>
    </configSections>
</configuration>

(snip)

<valveProfiles configSource="Profiles.config" />
```

in the Profiles.config:

```
<customProfiles>
    <curveProfile number="-1" name="Cusom1" />
</customProfiles>
```

However, the IDE has associated `Profiles.Config` file with the `DotNetConfig.xsd` schema, which expects the "customProfiles" to be declared in the configSections element, which the Profiles.config file does not have.

I am not particularily bothered by this as it basically only affects intellisense and generates misleading tooltips when you point at the blue undersquiggle, but I was surprised that google came up absolutely empty on this. And no, it is not because I included the word "undersquiggle" in my search ;)

Comment: If anyone is still looking, VS2008 does not import XSD extensions for custom configuration. If you use custom configuration, you will get schema warnings and, alas, undersquiggles.